# CakePHP 3 - Enable SSL on development server

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Does anyone know how to enable SSL on the development server that comes with CakePHP 3? I am trying to figure out where to put the certificates and what port number I should be accessing the development server on.

Comment: @ndm I agree. However, the OP might not know that CakePHP's implementation of its development server relies on PHP's own built-in server (it isn't mentioned in the docs). Perhaps it's a good idea to provide an answer.

Comment: @InigoFlores Actually, it is mentioned ;) **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server** However, you may of course provide an answer if you think it would be useful for future readers.

Comment: @ndm oops, yeah you are right! Second line... I think I need glasses :)